# Why is the image only partially visible inside my Button?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store app and I've done this before, months ago, but all of a sudden, in this new app, I can't get the image to display inside the button (properly).

```
    <Button x:Name="ShowView" Grid.Column="1" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,61,20,33">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="ShowViewImage" Source="/Assets/ShowView.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

As you can see, the code is fine (unless things have changed drastically, which by the looks of it they haven't). So what gives? This is the only code I have so far in my XAML file other than the defauls that VS generates as it's a new Project.

P.S. I've also tried taking out the StackPanel and just having Button > Image, but this produces the same result.

So, when the BUtton displays at runtime, all I can see is a very tiny, 2pixels of the image (but the image is actually *32x32pixels*. How do I properly display an "Image Button"?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  Does the whole button show and just not the whole image?  What width does Column 1 have in the grid?

Comment: Worth noting that you certainly don't need the `StackPanel` and, if anything, it's more likely to mis-size the image with that included.

Comment: I originally did _not_ have the StackPanel because I know it's not needed. However, when this code did not work I then went to MSDN and the only example they had of this that I could find had a StackPanel. So... When the right code doesn't work, Wtf am I supposed to do? Not try anything else?

Comment: Column 1 has more than enough width and height for the button. The button is exactly 32pixels, but the image inside it is 2pixels.

Comment: Try another image, does this occur with all images or just the one you are trying?

Comment: I just tried another one thank you @ToastyMallows. The problem still persists. I tried another image and also another image in a different format. I always use .png, but I just tried a diff image in bmp and jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Width` and `Height` for the button are far too small. You've made it 32x32 pixels, but the button will use almost all of that itself for the space it leaves around the visible border, the border itself, and the padding between the border and the button's content.

(It leaves space around the edge to provide a larger hit target than the visible appearance. This is useful on touchscreens, where accurate finger placement is difficult.)

All that's left for your image is a few pixels.

You'll need to make the button about 62x52 pixels to leave enough space in the middle for a 32x32 pixel bitmap.

You could get away with a slightly smaller button if you explicitly set smaller `Margin` and `Padding` properties, although as mentioned above, the margin is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I made the Button a little larger and all is well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options, the `Padding` property for instance is Template bound with some pre-set padding added to it. So with your `Button` having a fixed `Height` and `Width` set to 32 something as simple as setting `Padding="0"` could fix it for you depending on the actual size of your `Image`.

If worse comes to worse though, you could always just make your own `Button` Template. There's a couple easy ways to do this. One of which would be just go make a copy of the default `Button` Template, rip out all the Padding/Margin/Height/Width crap preset in there and just change its name then apply your new template directly to your button like;

```
<Button x:Name="ShowView" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,61,20,33" 
        Style="{StaticResource YourCustomButtonTemplateForImages}">
    <Image x:Name="ShowViewImage" Source="/Assets/ShowView.png"/>
</Button>
```

Or... another option would be, embed your `Image` inside of a `ViewBox` inside your button and it will fit and re-scale itself accordingly to its set available size.

Oh, you might also want to make your `Background="Transparent"` while you're at it to make it look a little cleaner as just an image.

Hope this helps.